# I can't understand why multi-threading code cannot get lineedit.text()

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I write code like under thing:

```
class QWidgetUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.IDinput = QLineEdit(self)
        self.searchBtn = QPushButton("",self)
```

And make multi-threading code like under thing:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):

    super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
    self.gui = QWidgetUI()

    self.worker = Worker()
    self.workerThread = QThread()
    self.worker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
    self.workerThread.start()

    self.connectSignal()

    self.gui.show()

def connectSignal(self):
    self.gui.searchBtn.clicked.connect(self.worker.conductCrolling)
```

And conductCrolling is like this:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def conductCrolling(self):
        j = 0
        searchingHtml = urlopen('https://www.twitter.com/{}/media'.format(self.gui.IDinput.text()))
```

In first code, `self.gui.IDinput.text()`has right value that I entered.
But in third codes, why line 8's `self.gui.IDinput.text()`doesn't have any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not access the GUI from another thread, nor with your code you can because in the function conductCrolling the self refers to an object of the Worker class, and clearly Worker does not have an attribute to gui. The solution is to pass as an argument to the text when invoking the conductCrolling function, for this you can use partial and a QTimer:

```
from functools import partial

# ...

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gui = QWidgetUI()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.workerThread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
        self.workerThread.start()
        self.connectSignal()
        self.gui.show()

    def connectSignal(self):
        self.gui.searchBtn.clicked.connect(self.launchTask) # change connection

    def launchTask(self):
        wrapper = partial(self.worker.conductCrolling, self.gui.IDinput.text()) # add text
        QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper) # invoked conductCrolling function
```

---

```
class Worker(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(str) # <---- add str
    def conductCrolling(self, text): # <--- add text
        # use text
        searchingHtml = urlopen('https://www.twitter.com/{}/media'.format(text))
```